# ROC Curve plot in tensorboard

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard

I want to plot a ROC curve through tensorboard in pytorch, I have read many posts regarding this but there is no mention of this. There is a facility for PR curve I believe but none for ROC curve. Is this feature available or possible in tensorboard pytorch?